# Error:View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL work bench 8 :

I am not able to create this view as I am getting following error:
View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Here is my view:

```
Create view history as
select ShippedDate, round(previous_operation) as DayEnd, DayStart ,Reorderunits,Quantity,reorderlevel from (
select
y.*
, @prev AS previous_Operation
, @prev := DayStart
from
ExpectedHistory y
, (select @prev:=NULL) vars
order by ShippedDate desc
```

Note : @prev holds an integer value

Comment: you cannot use variable or parameter

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? It contains a variable `@prev`, views don't support that.

Comment: In stead of using a view, you could use a stored procedure. Stored procedures can have parameters. Views cannot have parameters.

Comment: @sithj . . . Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the previous operation in MySQL 8+, use `lead()`:

```
create view history as
    select ShippedDate, DayStart,
           lead(day_start) over (partition by shippeddate) as as dayend,
           Reorderunits, Quantity, reorderlevel,
    from ExpectedHistory eh;
```

Comment: Hello,thank you very much,but lead and lag doesn't seem to work in version 8.I tried it

Comment: @sithj . . . (1) The answer uses `lead()`.  (2) `lead()` is definitely available in V8 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).